# When should the dependency from a core module be explicit?

Tags: .info

The [Standard profile](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!profiles!standard!standard.info.yml/8) declares the Node module as one of the modules it requires, and so does the [Minimal profile](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!profiles!minimal!minimal.info.yml/8). That is not true for the History module, which is required from the former but not the latter.

When should I declare my module as depending from a Drupal core module? Should I assume the installation profile / distribution always requires the module from which my module depends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In all versions of Drupal, if your module depends on another module, you should always explicitly declare it as a dependency.

Comment: Even Node module?

Comment: The Node module is optional in Drupal 8.

Comment: @user11153 The Node module doesn't contain `required: true` in its [node.info.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.info.yml/8), differently from the User module which contains that line in [user.info.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.info.yml/8).